# How to keep track of the height of a component in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to keep track of the height of a component from the moment it gets rendered to the DOM. I've tried a bunch of things but unfortunately to no prevail. I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-murdock-9g0x6?file=/src/App.vue) to better illustrate my problem.

I defined a property `oneCol` in my data object that looks like this:

```
oneCol: [
  {
    id: 0,
    component: KeepTrackOfHeight,
    height: undefined /*keep track of height here, but how?*/
  }
],
```

I then render that component with a simple `v-for` loop with the following code:

```
<div v-for="(component, idx) in oneCol" :key="idx">
  <component :is="component.component" :text="text"/>
</div>
```

Now I would like to keep track of the height of the component, so that from the moment it renders, the `height` in my `oneCol` property gets set to the height of the component. Also, when text gets added to the component, the height will obviously change. That change also has got to be reflected in the `oneCol` property.

I have not been able to set the initial width of the component in the `oneCol` property, let alone keeping track of height changes. I've tried setting a `ref` on the component and setting the height in the `mounted hook`:

```
mounted(){
    this.entries.forEach((entry, idx) => {
        this.oneCol.push({ idx: idx, component: KeepTrackOfHeight, height: this.$refs.componentName.$el.clientHeight})
    })
}
```

However, `height` will be undefined because the element will not be created yet.

Any help, info, ideas on how I can improve and keep track of the height would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to capture the height, there might be better approaches (e.g. CSS-only)... But if you use this:

```
mounted(){
this.$nextTick().then(()=> {
    this.entries.forEach((entry, idx) => {
        this.oneCol.push({ idx: idx, component: KeepTrackOfHeight, height: this.$refs.componentName.$el.clientHeight})
        })
    }
}
```

your DOM has finished rendering and $refs are available

[Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, yet for some reason `this.$refs.componentName` logs as undefined. I’ve been reading a few things about vuejs and found that nextTick references a nodejs object, and from what I read in the documentation this does not ensure that the document is actually rendered when executing this. So that may be the reason that it is undefined?

Comment: Not sure why nextTick isn't working, it actually should do the trick (but it's a bit difficult to replicate because your codesandbox doesn't have all the necessary code). How about setting an observer on the component instead? You can use the package vue-resize-directive, that works: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-gates-yj45r?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @Reinier68 and you have to remove the fixed height from the document to measure changes in clientHeight

Comment: Mate, this is EXACTLY what I needed... How in the world did you find that lib so quickly lol, honestly? I've spent hours and hours searching for a solution...

Comment: @Reinier68 I've come across the observer approach a few times and had seen that package before... Glad it works for you!